# Trying to run PHP in wordpress page code returns no results

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am using a plugin (shortcode tags top and bottom) to write PHP into a WP page.

However the code below returns no result other than 
"DONE 
Array
(
)"

The SQL (SELECT ID FROM wiz_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish') works fine from phpMyAdmin

```
[insert_php]
global $wpdb;
$myresults =$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb-
>wiz_posts WHERE post_status = d% ", 'publish') );
echo 'DONE <br>';
print_r ($myresults);
[/insert_php]
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help for an old dog learning a new trick?

ps this is running on a localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the placeholder correction as mentioned by @aynber. Also when selecting the table you shoudn't use the `$wpdb` global variable, so `$wpdb->wiz_posts` should be `wiz_posts`.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$myresults =$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM wiz_posts WHERE post_status = %s", "publish") );
echo 'DONE <br>';
print_r ($myresults);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The valid placeholders are:

- %s for string
- %d for integer
- %f for float

So since you're passing in a string, you want to use `%s`.

```
$myresults =$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->wiz_posts 
    WHERE post_status = %s ", 'publish') );
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed this but still no result :(

Comment: That worked. Many thanks for the help - onto the next challenge